# Is it possible to use Jinja2 macros outside of templates?

Tags: flask, macros, jinja2

I’m using the `fetch()` javascript API to partially update a page. The JS portion sends a JSON to a view in my flask app, which then returns a JSON to the page.

I’d like to send a rendered macro (as HTML code) as part of the JSON response, which I can use to update a portion of the target page.

Is it possible to use macros outside of templates so I can use it in my view function?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with calling the macro from a template ?

Comment: Could you share the macro you want to use outside of templates and add it to the question please?

Comment: You probably want to have some partial template for this, which is normally nested inside normal page template.

Comment: @pjcunningham The macro receives a dictionary as a default argument, and the dictionary contains color coding information that tells the macro what color to show if the status is "pending", "resolved", or "pinned". In keeping with the DRY principle, I was looking for a way to avoid writing the list again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is: use [get_template_attribute](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.get_template_attribute).

If your macro is e.g. defined in `_partial.html` as

```
{% macro hello(name) %}Hello {{ name }}!{% endmacro %}
```

Then you can execute it in your view like so

```py
hello = get_template_attribute('_partial.html', 'hello')
return hello('World')
```